# Accessing JS array data from an external JS file

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, arrays, backbone.js

I have a PHP script that generates a Javascript array and uses JSON to insert into this array into body of my web page.

Is it possible I can then access this array data with a Javascript file?

So, say the code on my page is:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> var park_data = [{"title":"Football Park"},"title":"Rugby Park"}]</script>
```

& I have

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
```

how do I access `park_data` using `script.js`?

---

**edit**

Ultimately, I'd like to have this in my `script.js` so the titles are shown in an infoWindow bubble:

> var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
>               content: park_data["title"]
>           });

However, right now it's not displaying the title :(

---

Thank you

Comment: what have you tried, did you try accessing it in that script.  I suspect you'll need to add window. to it to make it global like this var window.park_data =

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Unfortunately I'm *very* novice with Javascript so haven't tried much. Could you show me briefly how I would do this?

Comment: you can access the array memebers like so `park_data[0].title `

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Js variable park_data is available to your script.js , just include your script.js after you assign value to park_data
```

[here is your example] = http://jsfiddle.net/s4qU3/

Comment: Great - that works really well!! Now, how do I use this data? I am looking to add it to a Google Maps infoWindow. See amended question :-)

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript Variable **park_data** is automatically available to script.js if u include this javascript file after assigning value to **park_data** variable.

Comment: Can you show me how I access `park_data` within my `script.js` file?

Comment: With in web page demo.php, assigning value to javascript variable say
<script type="text/javascript"> var park_data = 'Hello'</script> 

Assuming script.js is included in footer.php

in script.js file 
just alert(park_data)... It will popup Hello

Answer (score 0):

For your amended question:

Get the Object from json data

**Example:** 
var mydata = JSON.parse(park_data);

alert(mydata[0].title);